# Question list shows question with marked answer but it has no accepted answer

Tags: bug, questions, accepted-answer, question-lists

Looking at a [list of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) I see a question with an accepted answer:

[image]

But going in to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637339/declaring-multiple-columns-in-a-count-value), the only answer there is not the marked answer:

[image]

Is this a bug? Was it accepted as the answer and then un-accepted? Caching?

**UPDATE:**

Stack Overflow saw this post and healed itself... the list now shows:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed for being off-topic / unable to reproduce, as it is a reproducible issue in the right circumstances. That close reason should be for things that are fixed and won't happen again as far as I see, this on the other hand could happen again in the right circumstances. The answer also highlights why it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *was* accepted when you loaded the list, but then got unaccepted after the load and before you opened the question. If you reload the list now, it no longer appears as accepted.

Comment: i did refresh the pages multiple times while posting and before clicking post, so i guess caching was to blame?

Comment: Yes, those lists are cached for something like a minute.

Comment: is there a way to view the history to show it was accepted and unaccepted like you can check post revisions?

Comment: Staff can view the accept vote in the timeline, but there's no way for a regular user to find this info.

Comment: Btw the timeline is here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43637339/timeline (question) and http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43637556/timeline (answer)

Comment: thanks @tom, that's what i was after... minus the acceptance part :-)

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed for being off-topic / unable to reproduce, as it is a reproducible issue in the right circumstances. That close reason should be for things that are fixed and won't happen again as far as I see, this on the other hand could happen again in the right circumstances.