# Question in the question list with accepted answer (green box) and no answers

Tags: bug, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

I came across this

[image: Question with green box but 0 answers]

in the questions search list.

The old question in question

- [Transparent generic exception handling for asp.net / MOSS2007 (with code)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/280412/11682469)

was closed as "unclear what you're asking" (not merged or anything)

[image: Closed as unclear what you're asking]

and really has **no** answer. The edit history also looks unsuspicious.

**What happened?**

---

Related questions I found:

- [Question list shows question with marked answer but it has no accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348455/11682469) (accepted answer was unaccepted without the OP noticing, so no bug)
- [Zero answers but accepted is "yes"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312267/11682469) (this is about review audits that I can't access)

Comment: there is an accepted answer but deleted (don't know how you can delete an accepted answer btw).

Comment: Still a bug, though.

Comment: @Temani Accepted answers can be deleted. They just can't be deleted by the answer's author. In this case, I wager it was deleted by animuson, since they were involved in closing the question in the first place.

Comment: @yivi I know, but it was not deleted by a Mod. It's only showing "deleted" which means by the one who added the answer (if I am not wrong)

Comment: @Temani. No idea.

Comment: It was deleted in 2011 by OP. There's a chance the block against deleting accepted answers wasn't around back then.

Comment: I've written an [answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238401/158100) about similar occurrences. The supporting [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/219659/questions-with-answercount-0-and-an-acceptedanswer-or-merged) does have your example question in its resultset.

Comment: @Zoe where do you see OP deleted it? [The timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/310398/timeline) doesn't even show it's been deleted. If I'm not mistaken this generally happens when an answer gets deleted along with its question's deletion.

Comment: @Zoe ... That's not what I'm asking. You made the claim that **OP** (a.k.a "owner") did delete this answer. We have no clue as if this claim is true or not. All we know is that this answer **is** deleted, for what we have, we don't see **how** it was deleted.

Comment: @Kaiido considering it says "deleted" and not "deleted by <one or more users>", it's likely it was self-deleted (unless the system changed that since 2011)

Comment: @Zoe nope, [self-deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56526338/wrong-encoding-while-csv-download/56573671#56573671) say "deleted by owner". and [their timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56573671/timeline) show a "deleted <owner> via Vote" history row. Here nothing.

Comment: That whole timeline is weird... I'm guessing something happened at a system level to remove data, or some kind of merge happened. One of OP's revisions talks about reverting code back to it's "original" state but none of the prior edits by anyone, including OP, changed the code.

Comment: Even weirder, I just went through the OP's entire rep history from account creation to the date the post was deleted ( Feb 5 '11 ) and there's no entry for OP getting +2 for accepting an answer to that question. I'm starting to think it is a case of two merged questions.